# Unable to start location service with google play services in android

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-service

I am starting location service with google play services but it is not working. It is not working in marshmallow and higher versions. There is no issue with permissions and there is no error but it is not passing location updates.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my service class file:

```
package com.Myapp.services;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.Loadmandi.Activities.DashboardActivity;
    import com.Loadmandi.Api.LocationApi;

    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        String TAG = "ConnectionService";

        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private Location previousLocation;
        public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 30000;
        public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
                UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;


        private Location mLastLocation;
        private Context context;

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBind");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            context = getApplicationContext();
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            if (checkPermsion(context)) {
                setupLocationService(context);
            }
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
          //  ApplicationCLass.isServiceRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind");
           // ApplicationCLass.isServiceRunning = false;
            return super.onUnbind(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
           // ApplicationCLass.isServiceRunning = false;
            LocationApi.stopLocation(getApplicationContext());
            super.onDestroy();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }

        private void setupLocationService(Context context) {
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();
                         createLocationRequest();

        }

        protected void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        public boolean checkPermsion(Context context) {
            int MyVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "in startLocationUpdates");

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
             FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,mLocationCallback,null);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Connected to onConnected");
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Connected to onConnectionSuspended");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Connected to onConnectionFailed");
        }

       LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "165 location is null");
                    return;
                }else{
                    Log.w(TAG, "167 location is not null");
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    // Update UI with location data
                    LocationApi.sendGpsLocation(getApplicationContext(),location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude());
                }
            };
        };

        private void stopLocationUpdates() {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }

    }
```

I am starting service from my activity by this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
                startService(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#java):

> Before requesting location updates, your app must connect to location
>   services and make a location request. The lesson on [Changing Location
>   Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings)
>   shows you how to do this. Once a location request is in place you can
>   start the regular updates by calling
>   [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback)).
>
> This lesson shows you how to get the update using the
>   [`LocationCallback`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#java)
>   callback approach. Call
>   [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)),
>   passing it your instance of the
>   [`LocationRequest`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest)
>   object, and a
>   [`LocationCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback).
>   Define a `startLocationUpdates()` method as shown in the following
>   code sample:
>
> ```
>  @Override protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>      if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
>          startLocationUpdates();
>      } }
>
>  private void startLocationUpdates() {
>      mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
>              mLocationCallback,
>              null /* Looper */); }
> ```